# How to have the real application-produced response schema in springdoc-openapi?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson, springdoc

I have a Spring Boot project using `springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui` to create an openapi-specification and show a Swagger UI. The project also uses Jackson to serialize data in JSON format. Jackson is configured to understand the `java.time` types and serialize them as strings (see the `@Bean ObjectMapper` configuration below). However, when running the project and looking at the Swagger UI, the openapi-calculcated response schema differs from the real serialization. See in the following two code snippets the difference in `test2` field, which is of type `java.time.YearMonth`. Also note that the schema calculation for `test1` field works, which is of type `java.time.Instant`.

Actual response:

```json
{
  "test1": "2023-11-06T10:53:42.781130500Z",
  "test2": "2023-11"
}
```

Response schema by openapi:

```json
{
  "test1": "2023-11-06T10:53:42.788Z",
  "test2": {
    "year": 0,
    "month": "JANUARY",
    "monthValue": 0,
    "leapYear": true
  }
}
```

This is the Controller:

```java
@RestController
public class TestController {
    @GetMapping("/test")
    public TestDto testDto() {
        TestDto testDto = new TestDto();
        testDto.setTest1(Instant.now());
        testDto.setTest2(YearMonth.now());
        return testDto;
    }
}
```

This is the model class:

```java
@Data
public class TestDto {
    private Instant test1;
    private YearMonth test2;
}
```

And the `ObjectMapper` configuration:

```java
    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
        return objectMapper;
    }
```

I know that I could do the following:

```java
@Data
public class TestDto {
    private Instant test1;
    @Schema(type = "string", format = "yearmonth", example = "2020-07")
    private YearMonth test2;
}
```

This would work: in the openapi-specification, the schema will be like this:

```json
{
  "test1": "2023-11-06T11:13:56.750Z",
  "test2": "2020-07"
}
```

Which is exactly what I want. However, I do not want to add this `@Schema` annotation manually, because this might affect multiple fields in multiple classes. I want the openapi-specification to have the exact response schema that is produced by my application. How can I achieve this?

Here is a MWE: https://github.com/SebastianOltmanns/springdoc-jackson